# Removing newline from string

Tags: android, listview, textview, newline, android-cursor

Here's my issue:
I have a database and it is full of episodes of a tv show.  One column denotes the episode number.  I want to display the episodes in a list like this:

- Episode 1
- Episode 2
- Episode 3
- etc.

I'm using my own adapter class that extends SimpleCursorAdapter to do this...
Since I had formatting errors I am using `Android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` and `Android.R.id.text1`

Basically the only reason I have a custom adapter is so I can do something like this:

```
textView.setText("Episode " + cursor.getString("column_for_episode_number");
```

The problem is, I get a list that looks like this:

- Episode
- 1
- Episode
- 2
- Episode
- 3

When I try something like this(which worked in a different portion of my code):

```
String text = "Episode " + cursor.getString("blah");
text = text.replaceAll("\\n","");
```

I get the exact same list output :(

Why don't I use create a custom view with two textboxes next to each other?  It is hard for me to get that to look pretty :/

Comment: What do you see if you log the values of `text`? I'm suspecting that your cursor is not returning what you expect.

Comment: If I log cursor.getString("blah") I get the correct number... then if I log "Episode " + cursorstuff I get the correct text (no newline shown there)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if there is new line at the beginning before you replace and do the same test again:

```
for(int i=0; cursor.getString("blah").length()-1; i++)
{

   if(cursor.getString("blah").charAt(i)=='\\n')  <-- use the constant for the line separator
    { 
      Log.i("NEW LINE?", "YES, WE HAVE");
    }

}
```

Or use the `.contains("\n");` method:

Check the xml for the width of the textview as well.

Why are you using `getString()` when you are fetching an integer? Use `getInt()` and then use `Integer.toString(theint)` when you are setting the values in a textview.

Comment: Does getString and getInt really make that big of a difference? Btw, it is the width of the textview that is the problem... nvm - figured it out

Comment: Use LayoutParams then look for the method to set the layout parameters (I forgot the name of the method) it was like textview.setLayoutParams(myLP); something like this, then add it to the layout or doit directly from the xml. set it to fill_pattern or wrap_content depends on how you want to look. DO NOT USE FIXED NUMBER OF PIXELS.

Comment: I forgot I had copied most of the customadapter from a different one and forgot to change the layout params - thanks !

Comment: No problem. +1 for well elaborated question.

Answer (score 12):

```
text.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a mistake in your code. Use "\n" instead of "\\n"

```
String myString = "a string\n with new line"
myString = myString.replaceAll("\n","");
Log.d("myString",myString);
```

Answer (score 2):

This could help you:

```
response = response.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are hitting wrapping issues rather than newline issues.  Change this:

```
String text = "Episode " + cursor.getString("blah");
```

To this:

```
String text = "Episode" + cursor.getString("blah");
```

And see if that changes the output.  Post your layout xml please?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for my (on android 4.4):

(where body is a string with a newline entered from an EditText view on handset)

```
for (int i=0; i<body.length(); i++) {
    if (body.charAt(i) == '\n' || body.charAt(i) == '\t') {
        body = body.substring(0, i) + " " + body.substring(i+1, body.length());                         
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried
        cursor.getString("blah").trim()